Flatlist not taking full hight
The FlatList is not taking the full height of the screen. When scrolling, the bottom portion of the FlatList is hidden, and it displays the background color of the parent view instead of extending fully.
Home.jsx
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import JobList from "../../components/jobs/JobList";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView className="flex-1 bg-secondary">
      <View className="flex-1 bg-white">
        <JobList />
      </View>
      <StatusBar style="light" />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Home;



JobList.jsx
import React from "react";
import { FlatList, View } from "react-native";
import JobCard from "../../components/jobs/JobCard";
import HomeHeader from "./HomeHeader";
import CategoryList from "./CategoryList";

const jobs = [
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "CHIEF ENGINEERING",
    company: "PT Vidya Artha Tama",
    type: "Contract",
    location: "On-Site · Bali",
    experience: "Min. Senior (>5 YoE)",
    salary: "Negotiable",
    activelyHiring: "2d ago",
    logo: "https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/circle-line-simple-design-logo-600nw-2174926871.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: "Dispatcher ASSA - Kota Bumi",
    company: "Anteraja",
    type: "Contract",
    location: "On-Site · Lampung Utara Regency",
    experience: "Min. Junior (1-3 YoE)",
    salary: "Rp 2.000.000 - 5.000.000",
    activelyHiring: "5h ago",
    logo: "https://img.freepik.com/premium-vector/minimalist-company-logo-template_1286368-92588.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    title: "Dispatcher ASSA - Kota Bumi",
    company: "Anteraja",
    type: "Contract",
    location: "On-Site · Lampung Utara Regency",
    experience: "Min. Junior (1-3 YoE)",
    salary: "Rp 2.000.000 - 5.000.000",
    activelyHiring: "5h ago",
    logo: "https://img.freepik.com/premium-vector/minimalist-company-logo-template_1286368-92588.jpg",
  },
];

const JobList = () => {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={jobs}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <JobCard job={item} />}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      ListHeaderComponent={
        <>
          <HomeHeader />
          <CategoryList />
        </>
      }
    />
  );
};

export default JobList;

I am trying to view the list jobs with full hight so when i scrolling i can see no issue

Please try with bellow codes.
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ height: Dimensions.get("window").height * 0.25 }} />
           <FlatList
              data={jobs}
              style={{ flex: 1 }}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
              renderItem={({ item }) => <JobCard job={item} />}
              showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
              ListHeaderComponent={
              <>
              <HomeHeader />
              <CategoryList />
              </>
              }
           />
    </View>

